# Doctrine2 and raw sql: get last inserted ID

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have something like this:

```
$stmt = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection()->prepare(
        'insert into someTable (columnList) values (parameters);');

/* 
bind parameters
*/

$stmt->execute();
```

How do I get the last inserted ID?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to use lastInsertId().

Example:

```
$dbh = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection();
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO continent (created_at, updated_at) VALUES ( NOW(), NOW() )");
$sth->execute();

$conn = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection();
$conn->lastInsertId('continent_id');
```

Comment: Yep, see also http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.1/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Connection.html#_lastInsertId

Comment: I tried it, and this is what I got
ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "Doctrine_Manager" from namespace "Joy\JoyBundle\Controller" in C:\wamp\www\joygroup\src\Joy\JoyBundle\Controller\JoyCreateCompanyController.php line 44. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?

Can you tell me what is wrong? why doctrine_manager hasn't been found?

Answer (score 1):

The code below answers the question correctly:

```
//This call will get the doctrine connection from inside a symfony2 controller
$conn = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection();
$stmt = $conn->prepare(
        'insert into someTable (columnList) values (parameters);');

/* 
bind parameters
*/

$stmt->execute();
$id = $conn->lastInsertId();
```

To get the connection from inside a doctrine repository class that you have created:

```
$conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
```